# Python: Getting error running python script

Tags: python, docker, numpy, alpine-linux

I am getting this error when I run a python script, I have my python settings in a Linux Alpine docker, I'm using python 2.7, the error is:

```
ImportError: C extension: umpy.core.multiarray failed to import not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

My environment has numpy=1.12.1.

Comment: Are you building your own docker image, or using an exiting one? If the former, please include the contents of your Dockerfile. If the latter, please state the name and tag of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the same problem as [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18281). You can find these answers by just Googling the error message.

It seems like wheels are broken for your version of numpy. Can you install a newer version of numpy?

Comment: I solved running this commands. apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev. And then I updated numpy.